# Guidelines to deal with class dependencies

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns

I have a doubt on the best approach to handle a class dependency and I was hoping to have some feedback on the issue.

Let's assume I have a class to model the Earth's ionosphere

```
class EarthIonosphere {
    // Methods that implement physical models of the Earth's ionosphere
}
```

To do some computations within `EarthIonosphere`, I might have the need to know the value of the Earth's magnetic model. Therefore I have an independent class for this:

```
class EarthMagneticField {
    // Methods that implement physical models of the Earth's magnetosphere
}
```

`EarthIonosphere` might depend on `EarthMagneticField` (but not the other way round). By the way, `EarthMagneticField` might also be needed in other parts of the code. With this in mind I was wondering which is the best solution (in terms of re-usability and maintainability) to approach this dependency. The two options I was considering were:

- `EarthIonosphere` contains a private/public member of class `EarthMagneticField`, but I am concerned on duplication in case the same `EarthMagneticField` has to be used in other parts of the code.
- `EarthIonosphere` contains a `std::shared_ptr` that points to an object of class `EarthMagneticField` that has been instantiated using the `new` operator. This would allow me to use exactly the same object to compute the magnetic field in other parts of the code.

Do you think any of these is a viable solution in terms of "clean code"? otherwise, do you have any suggestion like some "interface" class or similar?

Many thanks!

Comment: What kind of "duplication" are you concerned about? Is `EarthMagneticField` expensive to create? Does it use much memory? Does it have state that is expensive to calculate?

Comment: Yes, it might be a potentially "expensive" object in terms of calculations and it might also retain a set of coefficients locally to do the calculations. That is why in principle I would like to avoid duplication (plus I want to ensure that I am using the same `EarthMagneticField` in other parts of the code)

Comment: I think this problem description is too abstract. I could imagine `EarthIonossphere` taking `EarthMagneticField &` or `EarthMagneticField const&` in member functions which need it. The instance of `EarthMagneticField` would be created somewhere else, without any dynamic allocation to begin with. But this depends on the rest of the software architecture.

Answer (score 0):

A `shared_ptr` solution is certainly an idea, but I'd also think about storing a weak reference.

If there's only going to be `EarthMagneticField` around, you can instantiate it and then construct all other objects with a refence to it.

Answer (score 0):

If `EarthMagneticField` is cheap to create and there is no reason to share its state with other parts of the code I might be tempted to go with option 1 and just have it has a private member of class `EarthIonosphere`. You could always start with this option and refactor when you find you need to.

If you do need to share `EarthIonosphere`, I don't see any reason to use `new` and allocate dynamically. I would just create one outside of `EarthIonosphere` and pass a reference to the constructor of `EarthIonosphere`:

```
class EarthMagneticField {
};

class EarthIonosphere {
  EarthMagneticField* magnetic_field;
 public:
  EarthIonosphere(){EarthMagneticField& magnetic_field) 
  : magnetic_field(&magnetic_field) {}
};

int main() {
  EarthMageneticField magnetic_field;
  EarthIonosphere ionosphere(magnetic_field);
}
```

Comment: Why make the `magnetic_field` member a pointer, not a reference?

Comment: Isn't this solution similar to option (2), using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @RobK It could be a reference but reference member variables restrict what you can do with the class.

Comment: @Tryskele Similar, yes. There might be a (small) cost to using `new` but more importantly this way I think it is clearer that `EarthIonosphere` does not own `EarthMagneticField`.